# Jquery Value match Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I am trying to validate the input for E-Mail via JQuery:

My JQuery

```
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
  jQuery(function(){
   $( ".mail" ).keyup(function() {
   var VAL = $(this).val();
   var email = new RegExp(^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$);

   if(VAL.test(email)){
   alert('Great, you entered an E-Mail-address');
   }
   });
  });
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
```

This won't alert even though I entered example@example.com.
I already tried .test() and .match(), what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

- Pass a string to RegExp or create a regex using the `//` syntax
- Call `regex.test(string)`, not `string.test(regex)`

So

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(".mail").keyup(function () {
        var VAL = this.value;

        var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');

        if (email.test(VAL)) {
            alert('Great, you entered an E-Mail-address');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Take into account this will not accept lowecase letters.

Comment: It's a case sensitive expression so `abc@abc.abc` isn't accepted while `ABC@ABC.ABC` is approved. You can modify it to `'^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'` to solve the problem but there is another issue, in this Regex `abc@abcd` without any dot is accepted! I suggest this one instead: `/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/g` but none of these expressions accept an email address when there is a hyphen in domain name like: `abc@abc-abc.com`, visit this page for the best Regex: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: When constructing a RE with `new RegExp`, if you pass a sting, you'll need to double-escape backslashes. Eg you have `\.` in your code, but that's just an unnecessary escape character - `'\.' === '.'`. Best to avoid `new RegExp` unless you need to dynamically construct a RE from a variable.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly As this is a JQuery project, the standard DOM methods should not be used when possible. So `$(this).val()` is actually the better way of getting the value.

Comment: @leo848 `$(this).val()` just wraps `this.value` - it's one extra function call to get to the same piece of data, making it unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the same could be said about the whole jQuery library. It's purpose is to make DOM calls more accessible for the developer. Every single method could just be done with vanilla JS DOM manipulation. The jQuery website states that you should not mix jQuery-based manipulation with vanilla DOM manipulation. This is why I think `$(this).val()` should be used here. If you are more familiar with VanillaJS you could of course also just use `this.value`.

Answer (score 14):

Change it to this:

```
var email = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

This is a regular expression literal that is passed the `i` flag which means to be case insensitive.

Keep in mind that email address validation is **hard** (there is a 4 or 5 page regular expression at the end of Mastering Regular Expressions demonstrating this) and your expression certainly will not capture all valid e-mail addresses.

Comment: var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$', 'i');

Comment: I prefer to change it like this

Comment: I don't see anything different other than that you are using a string instead of the (arguably preferred) regular expression literal syntax?